# Modify Startup.cs code from Core to legacy ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, webforms, saml

I want to modify a legacy ASP.NET WebForms application to use Azure SAML authentication. I found SAML authentication sample for ASP.NET Core on Microsoft site and want to modify this code to fit in my Web Forms application Startup class.

The below code I want to change:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
  sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Saml2";
})
.AddSaml2(options =>
{
  options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("https://localhost:44342/Saml2");
  options.IdentityProviders.Add(
    new IdentityProvider(
      new EntityId("https://sts.windows.net/63eb1bcb-f74f-4703-8243-6f73d78ebf52/"), options.SPOptions)
      {
        MetadataLocation = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/63eb1bcb-f74f-4703-8243-6f73d78ebf52/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=9fd05134-d507-479b-a432-580541125356"
      });
  })
.AddCookie();
```

This code uses 'services' which is not available in my startup class. My existing code looks like this:

```
  public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            //interactive logon process
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
            //name of the authentication type
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            //Login path should be below
            // LoginPath = new PathString("login"),
            //TODO: Enable this to always send and receive cookies in SSL when in production
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            //enable sliding expiration
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            //Cookie expires in 4 hours
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4).Ticks)

        });
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {

            MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
            Wtrealm = realm
        });

        //This will set ADFS as the default authentication provider 
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what Microsoft SAML sample did you find?

Comment: @JasonPan Sure I will. I am checking the links.

Comment: @rbrayb I did not find any Microsoft sample for ASP.NET WebForms

Comment: OK - I was puzzled when you said "SAML authentication sample on Microsoft site" because there is no Microsoft SAML sample. There is a collection of client-side stacks here - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43

Comment: @rbrayb Sorry for that. I have been checking Microsoft or other samples but there are no examples for SAML authentication with Azure for ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: @rbrayb Is there any details on Microsoft site or any blog which says that there are no SAML code for ASP.NET WebForms.

Comment: Not that I'm aware. The SAML client-side stacks are language-specific, not platform-specific i.e. there is not one specifically for web forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Below article should be easy than previous. You can refer it.

[Code Your C#/ASP.NET App to Provide SSO via OneLogin](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/c-and-aspnet)

sample code : https://github.com/onelogin/dotnet-saml

## Previous

You can refer this doc learn how to fit your Web Forms application in `Startup.Auth.cs` class.

**Official doc :**

[*Sustainsys.Saml2 --ASP.NET Web Forms*](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/getting-started.html#asp-net-web-forms)

You also can refer this code.

[SampleOwinApplication](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Samples/SampleOwinApplication)

Comment: When I am trying to install Nuget, I am getting error: "Could not install package 'Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule 2.8.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does 
not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework."   .... Which framework it expects ?

Comment: The other issues I sorted out. I am getting error at this line:      app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create); . It is not able to find: ApplicationDbContext

Comment: @RKh I have updated my answer, hope it useful to you.

Comment: Thanks. I am checking the new link you have given.